# Add 2nd SSD internal drive HP EliteDesk 705 G4?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, desktop-computer

I have an `HP EliteDesk 705 G4` with one internal bootable SSD hard drive with `Windows 10`. I would like to add another internal SSD hard drive just so that I have access to it.

Does the `HP EliteDesk 705 G4` have the capacity for connecting a 2nd internal SSD hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your model.

The
[HP EliteDesk 705 G4 Small Form Factor](https://content.etilize.com/User-Manual/1048814330.pdf)
can only have one drive. It looks like this:

[image]

The
[HP EliteDesk 705 G4 MT Workstation PC](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c06151807)
can have two disks, a 3.5-inch and a 2.5-inch. It looks like this:

[image]